# Does Windows internet connection sharing support DHCP reservation?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dhcp

I have a rack full of computers connected to the internet via internet connection sharing (ICS) on one of the Windows 7 machines.  Two Axis IP cameras are connected to the rack.

Each time the system is re-started, the IP cameras end up with different IP addresses.  Unfortunately, the security software I'm running only allows cameras to be specified by IP address, and not by name.

According to Microsoft's documentation, ICS will not work with static IP addresses.  Is there any way to use DHCP reservation to achieve the same result?

Comment: Have you tried and confirmed yourself, that setting fixed IPs on the cameras does not work? (Pay attention to address conflicts.)

Comment: Will try fixed IP addresses if all else fails, but it looks like I'll be relying on luck to avoid DHCP-assigned addresses.